# Need expression to appear somewhere else

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report which uses an expression to provide data for each particular page. I have been able to get the report to display the correct data, however the column that the expression is in, is not necessary and the rest of the table will not fit on the page. I need to get rid of the column but reference the expression somewhere else on the report. I have tried a few things, such as referencing the text box but get Scope errors.

I would like the expression to display where the green line is, and make the first column invisible.

[image]

**Any ideas how I can reference the value of this textbox in the desired location?**

**Current state of report:**

expression `="Load Number: " & Fields!TPLD_SYS_NO.Value & "  |  " & "Vehicle:" & Fields!TPLD_TPVH_REG.Value & "  |  " & Fields!TPLD_REF.Value`

expression used to reference 1st expression `=ReportItems!TPLD_SYS_NO1.Value`

error `The value expression for the textbox 'textbox8' refers to the report item 'TPLD_SYS_NO1'. Report item expressions can only refer to other report items in the same grouping scope or a containing grouping scope`

Comment: I assume you tried copying the expression to the required cell and got an error? Please post your expression plus an errors that occurred.

Comment: @AlanSchofield Please see update

Answer (score 0):

This is from memory, zero testing I'm afraid so it might not be quite right but it should be close enough to follow.

A couple of options.

1. If the report will only ever show one value for this expression then you should be able to just use your original value expression directly in the 'new' text box but where you have `Fields!myField.value`, replace these with `FIRST(Fields!myField.Value, "myDataset")` where `myDataset` refers to the name of your dataset (you must include the quotes).
2. If the report is grouped so this expression will evaluate to two or more different values then you need to add a row inside the lowest group that will have all the required fields in either itself or child groups. As I guess I would say that would be the same level as your `Total` textbox. So `Insert Row / Inside Group Above` and then use the expression above but without the dataset name. You should be able to not specify this or if you get problems, specify it as the name of the rowgroup that your new textbox sits in.

Answer (score 0):

To get an out of scope value, you can create custom code functions to store the value and assign the text as follows :

```
="Load Details" + Code.Save_TPLD_SYS_NO(Fields!TPLD_SYS_NO.Value)
```

When you need to recall the value at some other point you can reference a function that returns the saved value like:

```
=Code.GetSaved_TPLD_SYS_NO(true)
```

In your custom code you can create a variable that will hold the value and that the function would be something like:

NOTE : This is untested and the code comes from memory, you may have to fiddle a bit to get the correct syntax.

```
Public Dim Shared TPLD_SYS_NO As String ="";

function Save_TPLD_SYS_NO(value As String) As String
Begin
  TPLD_SYS_NO = value
  Return ""
End Function

function DisplayAndSave_TPLD_SYS_NO(value As String) As String
Begin
  TPLD_SYS_NO = value
  Return value
End Function

function GetSaved_TPLD_SYS_NO(resetValue as Boolean) As String
Begin
   Dim result As String = TPLD_SYS_NO 
   If resetValue=true Then
      TPLD_SYS_NO = ""
   End If
   Return result 
End Function
```

Comment: After a second look, it appears that you are referencing a value above where the expression is defined. The code above probably does not apply to your situation. I think that Alan Schofield  is on to the correct answer. You will need to create a header of sorts for the group and refer to the fields using FIRST(Fields!xxxx.Value,"MyGroup")